# set a value to a dropdown generated in an ng-repeat (ANGULAR.JS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to recreate a real problem, so this example may seem strange, but it will certainly solve my problem.
I would appreciate it if you can help me.

I have a button, which clicks on it, it generates 3 dynamic dropdowns (a variable called $ scope.dropdown is fed, with the list of animals that contains the $ scope.aAnimals array, there are currently 3 elements, but in the future Can be "n" elements).

After this, I want each dropdown to have a different value, for example, that the first dropdown has the first animal, the second dropdown the second, the third dropdown the next.
I have tried many things, but I have not been able to achieve it.

```
<div ng-repeat='item in dropdown'>
     <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='MyAnimals' id='animal{{$index}}' name='animal{{$index}}'  
    ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals  track by opt.animal">
          <option style="display:none" value="">Select an animal</option>
     </select>
</div>
<button ng-click='add()' >generate</button>


$scope.obj = {}
$scope.aAnimals=
[
 { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
 { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
 { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
]


$scope.add=function(){
$scope.dropdown=[];
for(var i in $scope.aAnimals){
  $scope.dropdown.push({ "animal": $scope.aAnimals[i].animal })
  //$('.animal')[i].value=$scope.aAnimals[i].animal;
  }
}
```

this must be the result..

[image]

```
 { "animal": "cat"},  //first dropdown
 { "animal": "dog"},  //second dropdown
 { "animal": "parrot"}  //third dropdown
```

All animals continue to appear in all dropdowns. The important thing is to get the result of the image.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JF1PBblo6VGKdeWvoqTz?p=preview

Comment: So what is exact requirement here - Do you mean animal selected in first dropdown should not be part of second and third or on selection of same animal it should display validation message.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande a i need this http://i.imgur.com/gmiGamn.jpg

Comment: So does that mean on first dropdown selection you want to set other two with next available values?

Comment: @SumitDeshpande yes, i need set each one in the dropdowns

Comment: what @Sumit is trying to ask is whatever is there you have shown in the image. For that to achieve there can be several different ways/approaches. Which is the one you have to follow. Either validating them on select. Or automatically setting the values or something different.

Comment: @Manish I simply need a way to assign a different animal in each dropdown, that's all, as in the picture. My problem is not knowing how to set a value for a dropdown in this case.

Comment: @SumitDeshpande All animals continue to appear in all dropdowns. The important thing is to get the result of the image.

Comment: @Manish All animals continue to appear in all dropdowns. The important thing is to get the result of the image.

Comment: you do it with your model assigned to `ng-model` but you are using the same `ng-model` for all of them inside the `ng-repeat`

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I am something new in angular, but if I do not do so, I would have problems to achieve what I want. I do not know how to do it. Can you help me please.?

Comment: @yavg I am not able to see the images posted here(might be problem at my side) but from what you have described here I had the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330565/remove-select-options-from-other-select-boxes-based-on-current-selection-angul) a few months back. I have edited the fiddle which I had made there for your requirement. [See here](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/uuggsjey/12/). Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in dropdown'>
 <select class="form-control animal" ng-model='item' id='animal{{$index}}' name='animal{{$index}}' ng-options="opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals" >
      <option value="">Select an animal</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: ok. Just an aside, but you'd forgotten ng-app="app" in your plunker

Comment: This worked for me., pls tell me how it's showing on your side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use like -

```
<div ng-repeat="item in dropdown">
    <select ng-model="item.animal" ng-options="opt.animal as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals">
      <option  value="">Select an animal</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to keep "opt as opt.animal for opt in aAnimals  track by opt.animal"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
<div ng-repeat='item in aAnimals'>
   <select ng-model="item.animal" ng-options="opt.animal as opt.animal for opt in dropdownw"></select>
</div>
```